# CiviCRM installation page is blank on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am trying to install CiviCRM in Wordpress.

The upload and activation of the plugin worked fine.

Issue is now using this URL `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install` to complete the installation is failing.

All I am getting is a blank screen. I've checked the Safari console via "inspect element" and there are no error messages.

[image: Installation page screenshot]

Comment: What is your PHP version, civicrm version you are trying to install and CMS version?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions from the administrator manual? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress